# How to run a batch of sql files in a chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, oracle12c, chef-recipe

I need to run a few SQL script files in a chef recipe. 
When I execute the recipes using `batch` resource as below nothing simply happened.

```
batch 'cdb_scripts' do
    architecture :x86_64
    code <<-EOH    
      C:\\app\\Administrator\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus /nolog @C:\\app\\scri\\CreateDB.sql
      C:\\app\\Administrator\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus /nolog @C:\\app\\scri\\CreateDBFiles.sql
      C:\\app\\Administrator\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus /nolog @C:\\app\\scri\\CreateDBCatalog.sql
    EOH
    not_if {File.exists?('C:\scri\cdb')}
  end
```

Each script takes a considerable time to run and I need to proceed to the next script only after the previous script has finished. 
Nothing got executed with the above code.

I used `execute` resource as below:

```
execute 'test_script_execute' do
  environment ({"ORACLE_SID" => "orclsid"})
  command "C:\\app\\Administrator\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\sqlplus.exe -s sys/Password_123@orclsid as sysdba @C:\\app\\scri\\CreateDB.sql"  
  only_if  {some_guard_condition}
  timeout 1800
end
```

This simply logs "execute[test_script_execute] ran successfully".
But the script has not run.

In the task manager, the `sqlplus.exe` is running. Seems to be hanging instead of executing.

Can someone give me a working suggestion to run multiple SQL files in a sequence without overlapping with each other?

Thank you

Comment: Turn up the log level to `trace` (or `debug` if not on Chef 14) and look at the command output. It might be waiting for user input, which would mean waiting forever.

Comment: I need to create the spfile using pfile, then create a database as well. 
The environment variables were also set using a previous recipe, which sets them under system variables. When I run the `"ORACLE_HOME\bin\oradim.exe -new -sid orclsid  -startmode manual -pfile='C:\app\Administrator\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\database\initorclsid .ora';"` it got created, but the spfile creation script doesnt run and no failure message is also shown in the log ( under trace log level )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to simplify the requirement and execute a batch of scripts. 
I created a batch file and added the sql script calls there. It works perfect. 
Unfortunately there wasn't a direct way to call an sql script file directly which worked without errors. 
You can use the below code snippets if you have a similar requirement.

*Inside the batch file I put*

```
ORACLE_HOME\bin\sqlplus /nolog @C:\script_path\myscriptscall.sql
```

*Inside myscriptscall.sql*

```
set verify off
echo on 
spool C:\logs_path\scriptlogs.log

@C:\script_path\sqlscript1.sql
@C:\script_path\sqlscript2.sql
@C:\script_path\sqlscript3.sql

spool off
exit;
```

**Make sure to 'exit' after execution else the program will hang.**